# How to add a Gradient Layer to a Collection View Cell

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

I am attempting to add a gradient to a collection view cell as seen below:

[image]

So far the result I get does not cover the entire cell:

[image]

I have a
**collection view cell**:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    
    let diagonalGradient = DiagonalGradient()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        diagonalGradient.frame = cellView.bounds
        
    }
```

as well as a **Custom Gradient Class**:

```
class DiagonalGradient: UIView {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        setupGradient(color: UIColor.red))
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupGradient(color: UIColor.red))
    }
    
    func setupGradient(color: UIColor ) {
        
        gradient.colors = [
            UIColor.clear.cgColor,
            color.cgColor
        ]
        
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient.frame = bounds
        
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    
    }
}
```

Lastly, in the story board I assign the class of the cellView to my custom gradient class. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the gradient layer frame at the wrong time.

Move it to `layoutSubviews()`:

```
class DiagonalGradient: UIView {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        setupGradient(color: UIColor.red))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupGradient(color: UIColor.red))
    }
    func setupGradient(color: UIColor ) {
        gradient.colors = [
            UIColor.clear.cgColor,
            color.cgColor
        ]
        
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

        // don't do this here
        //gradient.frame = bounds
        
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // do this here
        gradient.frame = bounds
    }

}
```